# One column/two column form responsive layout using SLDS that preserves field ordering?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, slds

When I Google about responsive design, I find many examples where two areas that display side by side:

```
AAA BBB
AAA BBB
AAA BBB
```

display one after the other when the screen width is reduced:

```
AAA
AAA
AAA
BBB
BBB
BBB
```

But what I'm looking for is how to achieve (in SLDS) what the default detail page layouts in Lightning experience accomplish where individual fields go from neatly aligned two column layout:

```
F1 F2
F3 F4
F5 F6
```

to a single column layout with the left/right *field ordering preserved*:

```
F1
F2
F3
F4
F5
F6
```

Is there a simple recipe for this? (I don't see it mentioned in e.g. the SLDS [Grid](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/) documentation.)

Comment: instead of `slds-col` for columns, have you try using `slds-size_1-of-2 slds-max-small-size_1-of-1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is a visualforce example:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">
<head>
    <apex:slds /> 
    <style>
        .custom-container div {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="slds-scope">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-text-align_center custom-container">
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-max-small-size_1-of-1">F1</div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-max-small-size_1-of-1">F2</div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-max-small-size_1-of-1">F3</div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-max-small-size_1-of-1">F4</div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-max-small-size_1-of-1">F5</div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-max-small-size_1-of-1">F6</div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-max-small-size_1-of-1">F7</div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-max-small-size_1-of-1">F8</div>
    </div>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

Output in big screens:

```
F1    F2
F3    F4
F5    F6
F7    F8
```

As we have used [`slds-max-small-size_1-of-1`](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/sizing) sizing, for medium devices it gives output as:

```
F1
F2
F3
F4
F5
F6
F7
F8
```

This blog post explains it quite well: [Mastering Salesforce Lightning Design System Grids and Lightning Layouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/04/mastering-salesforce-lightning-design-system-grids-lightning-layouts.html)

Comment: Thanks - got some slight misalignment using `lightning:input` elements - but works surprisingly well.

Comment: Think the misalignment is that first `lightning:input` doesn't have a top margin but subsequent ones do (to provide vertical spacing). But when in two column mode, that pushes the second `lightning:input` down 8 pixels.

Comment: Removing `slds-form_horizontal` got rid of the spurious top margin and `slds-form_stacked` is less disconcerting in any case for this situation.

Comment: We are glad to be of any help. Thanks for letting us know about the issue.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `<lightning:layout>` or you can use Rahul suggested.

Component:

```
<aura:component >
    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="6" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="6">
            AAA
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="6" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="6" >
            BBB
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout  >
        <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="6" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="6">
            ccc
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="6" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="6" >
            DDD
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>


<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
    <span class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-max-small-size_1-of-1">AAA</span>
    <span class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-max-small-size_1-of-1">BBB</span>
    <span class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-max-small-size_1-of-1">CCC</span>
    <span class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-max-small-size_1-of-1">DDD</span>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Vignesh - thanks for answering too - +1 from me. I accepted Rahul's answer as he posted earliest (at least in the comment).